# Crystal Report tool bar not display in browser. VS2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

My crystal report toolbar not display when i execute report in my application.
My application develop in VS2008 with .net framework 3.5.
I am using built in crystal reports which is comes with VS2008.
My OS is Windows 7 Professional SP1.

Please give me the salutation ....!

Comment: May be the CSS you are using is conflicting with the Crystal Report's css and causing issue, try hitting F12 in browser and see if the tool bar's html is appearing there.

Comment: the toolbar html is not appearing in that

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Copy toolbar  images from

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\CrystalReportWebFormViewer3\Images\ToolBar

folder to some folder  on virtual root directory of your project.

In my case I used,  /Reports/ReportImages

After that change property of ReportViewer as below,

ReportViewer1.ToolbarImagesFolderUrl = "Reports/ReportImages/"

This is worked for me.

[Source](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/crystalreportviewer-toolbar-images-4594.aspx)

Comment: the problem is not of image the toolbar itself not appearing in the page